# Magento: How to query (SQL) top selling products?

Tags: sql, magento, report

Im seeking for a SQL query to directly get a list of our top selling products (ordered by quantity or by amount - doesn´t really matter). This seems to be more difficult than I thought...

Searching with google only finds solutions for PHP-modules and so on - but I want SQL.

I have picked up a small query from a different site and modified it a bit:

```
SELECT 
SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS ordered_qty, order_items.name AS order_items_name, order_items.product_id AS entity_id, 
e.entity_type_id, e.attribute_set_id, e.type_id, e.sku, e.has_options, e.required_options, e.created_at, 
e.updated_at FROM sales_flat_order_item AS order_items 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND `order`.state <> 'canceled' 
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity AS e 
ON 
-- (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle')) 
-- AND 
e.entity_id = order_items.product_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4 
--AND state = "complete"

WHERE (parent_item_id IS NULL) 

GROUP BY order_items.product_id 
HAVING (SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0)

ORDER BY ORDERED_QTY DESC
```

It more or less seems to give a reasonable output - but the numbers differ from the admin-start screen (where only the top 5 are displayed).

Has anybody done smth. similar to that already?

Answer (score 3):

Have a solution (query) now

```
select
        year_ordered, 
        product_type,
        sku,
        name,
        sum(qty_ordered) as qty,
        sum(row_total) as total
from (

SELECT 
    YEAR(so.created_at) AS year_ordered, 
    -- order_id, 
    product_type, sku, name, qty_ordered, price, row_total


   FROM `sales_flat_order` AS so
   INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS si ON si.order_id=so.entity_id
        AND (so.state != "canceled" )
 ORDER BY so.created_at desc

) stat

group by stat.year_ordered, stat.product_type, stat.sku, stat.name
order by year_ordered desc, total desc
```

I´m using a subquery to be able to control that counting the products is correct.

```
 SELECT 
        YEAR(so.created_at) AS year_ordered, 
        -- order_id, 
        product_type, sku, name, qty_ordered, price, row_total


   FROM `sales_flat_order` AS so
   INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS si ON si.order_id=so.entity_id
        AND (so.state != "canceled" )
 ORDER BY so.created_at desc
```

Result is a list of the ordered products per year. If you want to see a best seller list over all years a slight modification is sufficient (here ordered by total).

```
select
        product_type,
        sku,
        name,
        sum(qty_ordered) as qty,
        sum(row_total) as total
from (

SELECT 
    YEAR(so.created_at) AS year_ordered, 
    -- order_id, 
    product_type, sku, name, qty_ordered, price, row_total


   FROM `sales_flat_order` AS so
   INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS si ON si.order_id=so.entity_id
        AND (so.state != "canceled" )
 ORDER BY so.created_at desc

) stat

group by stat.product_type, stat.sku, stat.name
order by total desc
```

Comment: How can i get top-selling products based on level 2 category using mqsql query?

Comment: How to get a category-wise top-selling items list. @cljk

Comment: Worked perfecty. Many thanks.